# How to run Global Constant Function from Variable in Browser

Tags: javascript, function

I can access and run any function resides in window Object Using name String.
for e.g,

```js
function abc() {
  console.log("abc");
}
var str = "abc";
window[str](); // abc
```

but I want to know, is it somehow possible to run function declared with **const** keyword.

```js
const xyz = () => console.log("xyz");
const str = "xyz";
window[str](); // TypeError: window.xyz is not a function
```

Comment: It is if you attach the const to `window`, like this: `const xyz = () => console.log("xyz"); window.xyz = xyz;`.

Comment: @tex - If the OP could do that, he/she could simply write the call explicitly, too.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Gotcha. It took me a couple of minutes to think of a use-case for calling a function (specifically, one the caller didn't know about before runtime) via its string name, but I see the point now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **possible**, but the only way to do it I can think of is a Bad Idea™ in most cases: `eval` or its close cousin `new Function`:

```js
const xyz = () => console.log("xyz");
const str = "xyz";
(0,eval)(str + "()");
new Function(str + "()")();
```

The problem with `eval` (whether direct or, as above, indirect) and `new Function` is that they run arbitrary code from a string, firing up a full JavaScript parser to do so. Used incorrectly, that opens the door to XSS attacks or issues with inefficient code (though parsers are ***amazingly*** fast these days).

---

For any who don't know (I think the OP does): Global `const`, `let`, and `class` bindings are not added as properties to the global object like global `var` and `function` bindings are. That's why `window[str]();` won't work.

---

About

```
(0,eval)(str + "()");
```

above: that's an *indirect eval*. It works by separating the lookup of the identifier `eval` from the call, which breaks `eval`'s special link with local scope. In that case, it's using the comma operator to do that. Details:

You probably know that `eval` has access to local scope (and all containing scopes), so for instance this works:

```js
function foo() {
    const answer = 42;
    eval("console.log(answer);");
}
foo();
```

The code in `eval` can see `answer` because it has access to the scope where you called `eval`.

To try to limit the power of `eval` a bit, you can turn off its access to local scope and have it run its code at global scope instead by using `eval` *indirectly*. For instance, if you put it in a variable:

```js
function foo() {
    const answer = 42;
    const e = eval;
    e("console.log(answer);"); // Fails with ReferenceError
}
foo();
```

By separating the lookup of the identifier `eval` from calling the function it refers to, you break the special link it has with local scope.

The comma operator is one of JavaScript's more unusual operators: It evalutes its left-hand operand, throws away the result, evaluates its right-hand operand, and takes that value as the result of the comma expression:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("foo ran and returned 1");
    return 1;
}
function bar() {
    console.log("bar ran and returned 2");
    return 2;
}
const x = (foo(), bar());
console.log(`x = ${x}`);
```

Using `(0, eval)(str)` separates the lookup of the identifier `eval` from the call to the function just like assigning it to `e` did above. `0` is evaluated, thrown away, then `eval` is evaluated resulting in a function reference, and that function reference is the result of the comma expression; then we use it to `eval` `str`.

Comment: I **really** wanted `({[str]})[str]()` to work, but shorthand properties can't be computed... :-|

Comment: Sir, will you please explain why you put 0, before eval. I think we can also use it like this  eval(str+"()")

Comment: @MohammadFaisal - I only mentioned it very much in passing, didn't I? :-) I've updated the answer to explain it in detail. Happy coding!